# Getting Nullpointer Exception by adding an Arraylist to another Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Im having an Object which has some ArrayList as propoerties as you see below. Now im trying to use these object properties (ArrayList) to put in another Arraylist, but its not working and Im getting  a Nullpointerexception. The following source code illustrates my idea:

Class with Arraylist as object properties:

```
public class RawVector {


private long size;
private ArrayList<Float> x,y,z;
private ArrayList<Long> time;


public void setSize(long time){

    this.size = time;
}

public ArrayList<Long> getTime(){

    return this.time;
}

public void setTime(ArrayList<Long> time){

    this.time = time;
}
```

The Class testcsv in which i fill values in the ArrayList x,y,z of the Class RawVector:

```
 ......         ArrayList<Float> x = new ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<Float> y = new ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<Float> z = new ArrayList<Float>();


                File n = new File("C://file.csv");

                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(n);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            for(String zeile = reader.readLine(); zeile != null; zeile = reader.readLine()){
                StringTokenizer data = new StringTokenizer(zeile, " ,");


                x.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                y.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                z.add(Float.parseFloat(data.nextToken()));
                size++;



            }
            vector2 = new RawVector();
            vector2.setX(x);
            vector2.setY(y);
            vector2.setZ(z);
```

.....

The Class Segementation in which I want to assign the ArrayLists of class RawVector to another ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Float> sampleX = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Float> sampleY = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Float> sampleZ = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while(countersize <= (new RawVector().getSize())){


        Windowing wid = new Windowing(); 

        for(int i = 0; i <= m.getWsize() ; i++){

            if(i <= (new RawVector().getSize())){


                sampleX.add(rv.getX().get(i));
                sampleY.add(rv.getY().get(i));
                sampleZ.add(rv.getZ().get(i));
            }
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Segementation.getwindow(Segementation.java:69)
    at Segementation.main(Segementation.java:95)
```

line 69 stand for:

```
sampleX.add(rv.getX().get(i));
```

The idea behind this line is to get the value of i in Arraylist x and to add it to the new ArrayList sampleX

I know you will get an NullpointerException if you dont intialize your Arraylist. But I was pretty sure my ArrayList x of the class RawVector is intilaized by assigning values through the class tescsv.

I hope my problem is straightforward. I would be very grateful for any help!!!!!!
Thankls in advance.

Comment: The exception occurs in the `getwindow` method, which you haven't shown us in full. You've shown us a lot of *snippets* of code code, badly formatted, but missed out the most important bit. Please reduce your code to a *short* but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem... *then* we can help you.

Comment: Are you sure that all objects on line 69 of class `Segemetation` have been properly initialized?

Comment: I don't know your whole code, but something has not been properly initialized. Either rv is null or rv.getX() is null.

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome: you are totally right the reference of rc is null.

Comment: What can I do to use the created ArrayList in the Class testcsv in another Class? I mean how can use the ArrayList of the RawVector object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing a class with an instance. The `RowVector` class initializes **instance** fields `x`, `y`, and `z` to `null`. (It's not explicit, but that is what happens when you do not give an initial value to any field of a class.) In your third code block you are instantiating a new `RawVector` object, and you are not setting any of the arrays before trying to reference `getX()`. The fact that you called `vector2.setX(x);` in  the second code block has no effect because it is to a different instance of `RawVector` than the one used in the third code block.